# How can I set and get the data from the spinner In a recycler'View's item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, spinner, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have a recyclerview & each row has a spinner. So My problem is retrieve items data from spinner its populate last loaded spinner items how can I solve it ..

**Adapter.java**

```
public class TellUsMoreSpecificSchemesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TellUsMoreSpecificSchemesAdapter.ListViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    private static List<TellUsMoreAboutSpecificSchemesClass> tellusmoreaboutschemesarray = new ArrayList<>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Listener listener;
    ArrayList<String> TellUsMoreAboutList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> TellUsMoreAboutList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayAdapter<String>> arrayAdapter= new ArrayList<ArrayAdapter<String>>();

TellUsMoreSpecificSchemesAdapter adapter;



private static MyClickListener myClickListener;

LinearLayout layout;



public TellUsMoreSpecificSchemesAdapter(Context context, List<TellUsMoreAboutSpecificSchemesClass> dataList1) {

    this.context = context;
    tellusmoreaboutschemesarray = dataList1;
    this.listener = (Listener) context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

@Override
public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tellusaboutrecommendingspecificschemes_list_row_view, parent, false);

    ListViewHolder viewHolder = new ListViewHolder(convertView);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, int position) {


    String spinnerValue = tellusmoreaboutschemesarray.get(position).getQa_values();
   TellUsMoreAboutList.clear();

    String[] items = spinnerValue.split(",");
    for (String item : items) {


        TellUsMoreAboutList.add(item);


    }


    holder.spinnerQuestion.setText(tellusmoreaboutschemesarray.get(position).getQuestion());


    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, TellUsMoreAboutList);


    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    holder.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    holder.spinner.setId(++chId);



}

public TellUsMoreSpecificSchemesAdapter(List<TellUsMoreAboutSpecificSchemesClass> dataList1, Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    tellusmoreaboutschemesarray = dataList1;
    this.listener = (Listener) context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
    TellUsMoreSpecificSchemesAdapter.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    if (tellusmoreaboutschemesarray == null || tellusmoreaboutschemesarray.size() > 0)

        return tellusmoreaboutschemesarray.size();
    else
        return 0;
}

class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View
        .OnClickListener {

    TextView spinnerQuestion;
    ImageView hint;

    Spinner spinner;

    View taskPriority;

    ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

         spinnerQuestion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTellUsMoreAboutRecommendSchemes);
        hint = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivTellUsRecommendingSchemesactivity);


        layout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);



        spinner = new Spinner(context);
        layout.addView(spinner);

        spinner.setId(++chId);

        hint.setOnClickListener(this);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });


        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        myClickListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition(), v);


    }
}

public interface MyClickListener {

    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    tellusmoreaboutschemesarray.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, tellusmoreaboutschemesarray.size());
}  }
```

Comment: Thanks in advance ......

Comment: Thanks Neo bhai ........

Comment: What is this ++chId ... Please Tell me Guys!

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution.......

```
    String spinnerValue = tellusmoreaboutschemesarray.get(position).getQa_values();
    final String hintSpinner = tellusmoreaboutschemesarray.get(position).getHint();
    holder.spinner.setPrompt("Select value");
    TellUsMoreAboutList.clear();
    Log.d("Data", "Debug Data hintSpinner:" + hintSpinner);
    Log.d("Data", "Debug Data spinnerValue:" + spinnerValue);
    int xo = 0;
    String[] items = spinnerValue.split(",");
    for (String item : items) {

        TellUsMoreAboutList.add(item);
    }
    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    for (int i = 0; i < TellUsMoreAboutList.size(); i++) {
        holder.spinner = new Spinner(context);

        holder.spinner.setId(i);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.add(TellUsMoreAboutList.get(i));

    }

    holder.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    layout.addView(holder.spinner);
```